# Select option are in "_listener" attribute

Tags: selenium, xpath

Have a tag like:

```
<select class="xyz"_listener= "<select class="gwt-listbox"><option value="Select the option"></option> <option value="Name1"></option> <option value="Name2"></option> <option value="Name3"></option> </select>" </select>
```

If we have options are under select tag, we could take using select class. But here all select value(Name1, Name2, Name3) are being in `_listener` attribute.

So How could we get the value and give input for drop down box in selenium?

Comment: The html would be changing when you click on the select box, try and see

Answer (score 0):

Try using the concat function to append double quotes in the value as below

```
    \\select[@_listener='concat('<select class=',",'gwt-listbox',",'<option value=',",-----------------]
```

Hope this will work..